# Pass data between components when using ng-content

Tags: angular

I have some components that I use in my app to create cards:

```html
<app-card-container>
    <app-card-title>Card title</app-card-title>
    <app-card-body>
      // some content
    </app-card-body>
</app-card-container>
```

I want to add a functionality where the `body` component can be collapsed (height: 0).

```html
// card-container

<div class="cardContainer"
    [ngClass]="[
        variant
    ]"
>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```html
// card-title

<h4 class="cardTitle" translate>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</h4>
```

```html
// card-body

<div class="cardBody">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I want to keep my templates clean so move the logic to the components but I'm not sure what my options are. I'm thinking of creating a service that the components can subscribe to and detect the changes but that might not work if there's multiple collapsible card-container components on one page.

Comment: @angular/material source code could be a very good source of inspiration for you. Check the code : https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/material/expansion

Comment: I would do it [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/card/card/card.component.html). Additionally you could create a component `bs-card-body` projecten with `<ng-content select="bs-card-body">` but it's not really necessary... The collapsing can be done through an `@Input()` and `*ngIf`

Answer (score 0):

I think an accordion is what you are trying to do , you could check this [post](https://sreyaj.dev/customizable-accordion-component-angular)